# Kafka Streams: DeserializationExceptionHandler with config parameters

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am not familiar with the Java reflection.  MyCustomException class implements the 
DeserializationExceptionHandler interface and in the streamsConfig, I understand that class can be supplied.  However, is there a way to supply the ***`configs`***  (in the configure method) along with the class?  Can you please provide a sample code?

```
streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, MyCustomException.class);
```

.

```
public class MyCustomException implements DeserializationExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passed in `Map<String, ?> configs` parameter should contain all configs that you add to the `Properties` you pass into `KafkaStreams` constructor. Thus, you can just add the configs you need there and it will be forwarded accordingly.